# Extract tensor shape as integers with unknown first dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I have a function where it takes as input a tensor X. I would like to extract the 2nd, 3rd and 4th dimension sizes from a Tensor whose first dimension is unknown:

I wrote the following code but it does not work:

```
x = Input(shape=(128, 128, 1))

def function1(x):
    sz = tf.shape(x)
    row = int(sz[1].numpy())
    col = int(sz[2].numpy())
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

I have also tried:

```
sz = tf.TensorShape(x).as_list()
```

but the error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot iterate over a tensor with unknown first dimension.
```

I'm using Tensorflow 2.1

Comment: Try `print(x.get_shape().as_list())`

Comment: It works! I actually tried the get_shape method but it gave me error. I cant remember excatly how I called it previously but it works now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_shape()`.

```
print(x.get_shape().as_list())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `x.shape`:

```
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128, 128, 1))

n, row, col, channels = x.shape
```

This is what `x.shape` returns:

```
TensorShape([None, 128, 128, 1])
```

Or like this:

```
row, col, channels = x.shape[1:]
```